# Why it is wrong? (differentiation under the integral sign)

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Why is it wrong?
$$
\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\int_{-1}^1\log|x-t|dt=\int_{-1}^1\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}\log|x-t|dt=\int_{-1}^1\frac{-1}{(x-t)^2}dt.
$$

Comment: What is the domain of $x$?

Comment: No information about the domain of $x$.

Comment: what should the answer be?

Comment: Want to show why I cannot exchange the order of differentiation and integral.

Comment: If $x\in [-1,1]$, the integral diverges already for the first derivative. If $x$ is outside this interval, I don't see anything wrong with this.

Comment: I think Lukas's comment is also true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh boy... let's try defining the second derivative as a difference quotient:
$$ f''(x) = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \frac{f(x+\epsilon) - 2f(x) + f(x-\epsilon) }{\epsilon^2} \text{ where } f(x) = \int_{-1}^1 \log |x-t| dt $$
Now let's try it with your integral:
\begin{eqnarray}\frac{d^2}{dx^2} \int_{-1}^1 \log |x-t| dt &=& \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \frac{1}{\epsilon^2} \int_{-1}^1 \log \left| \frac{(x-t)^2-\epsilon^2 }{(x-t)(x-t)}\right| dt \\ &=& \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \frac{1}{\epsilon^2} \int_{-1}^1 \log \left|1 - \frac{  \epsilon^2}{(x-t)^2}\right| dt\end{eqnarray}

As long as $|x - t| > \epsilon$ we can use Taylor approximation $\log (1 - x) = - x + O(x^2)$:

$$  \frac{1}{\epsilon^2} \int_{-1}^1  \frac{  -\epsilon^2}{(x-t)^2} dt 
= \int_{-1}^1  \frac{  -1}{(x-t)^2} dt $$
So $f(x)$ is divergent whenever $x \in [-1,1]$.

---

In that case, you may wish to consider $f(x \pm i\delta)$

Comment: I think john's proof is sufficient to show that I cannot exchange the order of differentiation and integral. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Setting
$$
I(x):=\int_{-1}^1\log|x-t|dt,
$$
we have
$$
I(\pm1)=2\log2-2,
$$
and for every $x \in \mathbb{R}\setminus\{-1,1\}$:
$$
I(x)=\left[(t-x)\log|t-x|-t\right]_{-1}^1=(1-x)\log|1-x|+(1+x)\log|1+x|-2.
$$
Clearly
$$
I''(x)=\int_{-1}^1\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}\log|x-t|dt \quad \forall x \in \mathbb{R}\setminus\{-1,1\}.
$$
Furthermore $I$ is not differentiable at $x=\pm1$, and therefore $I''(\pm1)$ does not exist.

---

**Added** 
For every $x \in \mathbb{R}\setminus\{-1,1\}$ we have
\begin{eqnarray}
I'(x)&=&\log|1+x|-\log|1-x|=\int_{-1}^1\frac{dt}{x-t}dt=\int_{-1}^1\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\log|x-t|dt\cr
I''(x)&=&\frac{1}{1+x}+\frac{1}{1-x}=\int_{-1}^1\frac{-1}{(x-t)^2}dt=\int_{-1}^1\left(\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}\log|x-t|\right)dt.
\end{eqnarray}
Now the cases $x=1$ and $x=-1$. We just treat the case $x=1$, the other one (i.e. $x=-1$) can be treated in the same manner.

For every $h \ne 0$ we have
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{I(1+h)-I(1)}{h}
&=&\int_{-1}^1\frac{\log|1-t+h|-\log|1-t|}{h}dt
=\int_0^2\frac{\log|s+h|-\log|s|}{h}ds\cr
&=&\frac{1}{h}\left[(s+h)\log|s+h|-s\log|s|\right]_0^2\cr
&=&\frac{(2+h)\log|2+h|-2\log2}{h}-\log|h|.
\end{eqnarray}
It follows that
$$
\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{I(1+h)-I(1)}{h}=\infty
$$

Comment: Thank you very much, Mercy and john, for your prompt responses. I just need time to undertstand your answers. I notice there is a difference between your conclusions. Mercy said the equalities in the problem are fine except at -1 and 1; john said it is fine except [-1,1]. I tested them by x=0, and found it is not divergent and both get the reult 2. Thus, I think probably Mercy is correct.